# Changed selection color of UITableViewCell, but it still changes the UILabels font colors. How do I prevent this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I changed the background color of UITableViewCell when selected with this:

```
UIView *selectedBackgroundColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
[selectedBackgroundColor setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:240/255.0 blue:240/255.0 alpha:1]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundColor];
```

But it still changes the color of the UITableViewCell's labels to white, which I don't want. Can I stop it from doing this by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `highlightedTextColor` property of the textLabel as well:

```
cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.123 green:0.32163 blue:0.54647 alpha:1.0];//or whatever color you want
```

If you don't want the text color to change when selected, set this color to the same color as the `textColor` property of the textlabel.

```
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.123 green:0.32163 blue:0.54647 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: `textColor` is deprecated.

Comment: No it's not. Check again ---> cell.textLabel.textColor

Comment: Is there a way to do this with UIAppearance? I want to change the color of all the UITableViewCell selection colors.